# How make kubernetes job fail with it cannot find the pod image?

Tags: kubernetes

When a container image is not present on the cluster the pod fails with the error `ErrImageNeverPull` but the job never fails. Is there a configuration that I can add to make sure the job fails if the pod startup fails.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: image-not-present
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 120
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: consolehub
      containers:
      - name: image-not-present
        image: aipaintr/image_not_present:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 1):

You can config **activeDeadlineSeconds** for this case. However, you have know how long your job take to reach **Complete** status to avoid this timeout can kill your pod processing.

From the [documents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup):

> The activeDeadlineSeconds applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

For example: I have created job with wrong image and **activeDeadlineSeconds**: 100. Obviously, the pod stuck with status **Pending** because of wrong image.[kubectl describe pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5y4i.png)

After 100 seconds, the Job was **Fail** and the pod was killed as well.
[kubectl describe job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJpT1.png)

Comment: This will not work for jobs that take few mins to few hours. In my use-case a job can run for upto 4 hours(machine learning task). Is there a way to know if the job is stuck due to some failure.